# Firebase REST API - POST Request

Tags: rest, firebase, post, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to add records to my Firebase database as follows:

[image]

So basically we have `matches` -> `user_supplied_id` -> `{id,location}`

This is achievable using the following code and the Swift API:

```
let matches = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "uid") as! String).child("matches").child((all_listings?[index].listingId)!)

let newBookData = [
    "id": all_listings?[index].listingId,
    "location" : all_listings?[index].location
    ] as [String : Any]

matches.setValue(newBookData)
```

I am now trying to replicate this behaviour using the Firebase REST API. I'm basically sending a `POST` request to the address:

`https://PROJECTID.firebaseio.com/.../matches/-LOpJmU9yj4hAocHjnrB.json`

with the following data:

```
"{\"id\":\"-LOpJmU9yj4hAocHjnrB\",\"location\":\"Edinburgh\"}"
```

However, this results in the following outcome instead:

[image]

As you can see, it creates an additional ID and level of nesting before adding the elements to the database. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use POST.  According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/#section-post):

> To accomplish the equivalent of the JavaScript push() method (see Lists of Data), you can issue a POST request.

You don't want a push here.  A push operation creates a new random push ID and makes that the key of the data you provided.

If already you know the location you want to set (it looks like you already have a known push id), just use a PUT to set the data at that location.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just a quick comment regarding the previous version of this question, the reason I removed the `F#` code and tags is mainly because I feel like it puts potential answerers off because they aren't familiar with `F#`, whereas the question itself has little to do with `F#` as once I know what the request needs to look like, I know how to implement this in `F#` myself.